# BinaryFormatter Deserialisation throws exception when used through COM interop

Tags: c#, vb6, com-interop

I have to update some old applications (vb6) and I have been using COM interop to write the new code in c# (Visual Studio 2010). Its mostly worked OK but I have come across a problem and I am not sure what is causing it.

I use the following method to perform a deep copy of an object

```
    public static T CloneObject<T>(T source)
    {
        T destination = default(T);

        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serialisable.", "source");
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, source);
            ms.Position = 0;

            destination = (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }

        return destination;
    }
```

For some reason the code errors out when the Deserialize function is called. The exception that it throws is that the assembly that the code is in cannot be found.

> Unable to find assembly 'AssemblyBeingUsed, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

This is slightly confusing me as the assembly is already being accessed and its saying that it cannot be found. The code that formats the error message is part of the same assembly!

Here is the stack trace for the exception.

> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)

**Edit**: More useful information.

This function is never called directly from vb6. As it uses generics I'm pretty sure that this would be impossible anyway. This function is called from a form which is loaded from the vb6 application. When this form is used from a c# application there is no problem even though it is doing the exact same thing.

The Visual Studio project uses the "Register for COM interop" option and the assembly is loaded into the vb6 project as a reference.

**Edit**: Output from fuslogvw.exe

The output from fuslogvw.exe shows 5 entries associated with the assembly I'm interested in (BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase). As it is quite long when they are combined I have uploaded all the output to 
[this file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVO5d3FFOaqOGwwUGEtcjRzSms).

To be honest I'm not sure what I'm looking at. There are 3 operations that I think correspond to when the assembly binds occur:

15:29:06: VB6 application started, operation was successful.

15:29:14 (2 entries): Form from assembly loaded (I think), operation failed. This is sort of confusing as the form loads correctly and can be interacted with.

15:29:50 (2 entries): Button click that fails when the CloneObject method is called, operation failed.

Comment: Bit of a wild shot but do you have dlls in more than one directory? If you do you get this sort of twilight zone behaviour when 2 copies of the same dll can be found by the exe.

Comment: It looks like you are having issue with parsing an integer.  Does the input have nulls?  Try int? instead of int.  Do the integers have decimal places (period or commas)?  Are there spaces between the +/- and the number?  VB is a little better at handling different formats for numbers.

Comment: Clearly not using the GAC, I smell an Assembly.LoadFile() rat.

Comment: @AdamBenson There are no copies of the dll in the vb6 project directory. There is an option to register the assembly for COM interop and then I reference it in the vb6 project.

Comment: @jdweng The same function is run from a c# application and this works, I've edited the post to explain more about the context from which the code is run.

Comment: @HansPassant I assume that the "Register for COM interop" handles loading assemblies to the GAC. I don't use Assembly.LoadFile anywhere.

Comment: It does not, it use the equivalent of Regasm.exe /codebase.  Nor could your assembly ever be loaded in the GAC, it does not have a strong name.  You can only get more than a blind guess by posting the trace you get from Fuslogvw.exe

Comment: @HansPassant I've uploaded the output from fuslogvw.exe.  Would you be able to give me some pointers for what I am looking for?

Comment: I don't know if you are still seeking a solution, but I set up a test project using Office VBA instead of VB6 and I reproduced your issue.  I don't know the exact reason for the problem.  A workaround is to handle the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and return `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` from the event handler.

Comment: @TnTinMn I'm not currently able to test this until next week but I shall let you know the results when I do. Should this be posted as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @TnTinMn That seems to have sorted it. I had a problem when it was trying to access assembly resources because of an icon on a child form which I never really solved. The form wasn't showing the icon anyway so I removed it but it might be a problem later. Do you want to write your solution as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad that that resolved your primary issue and I will post it as an answer later today.  I have been trying to research the root cause of the problem and I am fairly certain that it related to the assembly's _load context_.  However this is an area that I do not have a firm grasp on as I found the available information to be lacking on many fronts.  I found a reference that states that it is possible for an assembly to be simultaneously  loaded in multiple load contexts and that are treated as separate types. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR Version:

The system can not locate the assembly.  The solution is to add a handler for [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event and return a reference to the needed assembly.

Long Version:

The stack trace finishes with [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binarycommonclasses.cs,9c1c2f7736b1913d).  If you follow the method calls in the source code a bit further down the chain, you will see that this following code is called.

```
    internal static Assembly LoadAssemblyFromString(String assemblyName) {
        //
        // Try using the stringized assembly name to load from the fusion cache.
        //
        BCLDebug.Trace("SER", "[LoadAssemblyFromString]Looking for assembly: ", assemblyName);
        Assembly found = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        return found;
    }
```

The fusion log of this call is:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (14/06/2017 @ 15:29:50) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/VB98/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vb6.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

The problem is that the system is probing the directory listed under 'Appbase` (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98) and since required assembly is not located under that directory, it is not found.

Intitially when COM loads the CLR and the CLR loads the assembly, it is  based on the path stored in the registry.  This can be seen from this log entry.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = D:/Development/Library/C Sharp/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase/bin/x86/ComInterop/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/VB98/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vb6.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Development/Library/C Sharp/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase/bin/x86/ComInterop/BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: D:\Development\Library\C Sharp\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase\bin\x86\ComInterop\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Re-apply policy for where-ref bind.
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from D:\Development\Library\C Sharp\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase\bin\x86\ComInterop\BarcodeAndOperatorDatabase.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.
```

Initially the assembly exists only in the `LoadFrom load context` and can not be found when probing the `default load context`.  It is therefore necessary to provide a means to pass the `LoadFrom` assembly while probing the `default load context`.  This can be done by handling the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event.

The following excerpt from: [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading#avoid-loading-an-assembly-into-multiple-contexts) provides a description of the various contexts.

> Within an application domain, assemblies can be loaded into one of
>   three contexts, or they can be loaded without context:
>
> The default load context contains assemblies found by probing the
>   global assembly cache, the host assembly store if the runtime is
>   hosted (for example, in SQL Server), and the ApplicationBase and
>   PrivateBinPath of the application domain. Most overloads of the Load
>   method load assemblies into this context.
>
> The load-from context contains assemblies that are loaded from
>   locations that are not searched by the loader. For example, add-ins
>   might be installed in a directory that is not under the application
>   path. System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom,
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom, and
>   System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly are examples of methods that load by
>   path.
>
> The reflection-only context contains assemblies loaded with the
>   ReflectionOnlyLoad and ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom methods. Code in this
>   context cannot be executed, so it is not discussed here. For more
>   information, see How to: Load Assemblies into the Reflection-Only
>   Context.